# How would I find on iMDb, all male actors with movies debuts between ages 20 and 30?

Tags: data-request, film

It would be like asking each male actor personally: **Which movies were you in when you were between the age of 20 and 30?** To be clear, that would be 30 years and 364 days old.

For example, for today, this would find me actors like: Miles Teller (Whiplash), Ellar Coltrane (Boyhood), Evan Peters (Kick-Ass), Aaron Taylor-Johnson (Kick-Ass)

But of course I'd like an overview of all time, so also movie titles that had male debutants aged 20-30 in 1970 or in 1889.

I think this would involve some query that compared **Actor-Birthdate** to **Movie-Shooting-Date**.

This might be conceptually as follows:

```
IF **Actor-Birthdate** -/- **Movie-Shooting-Date** > 20 but < 30
  then give **Movie-Name**.
```

This query or algorythym or function has to be performed on every single male actor, I guess.

I would need actor datasets with their D.o.B, the movies they made and the film shooting dates of those movies.

I suppose the IMDb site itself does not offer tools to do this, so I guess it would have to be imported into some database program like SQL or Wandora. Or Excel or MS Access

I'd be very happy if anyone had any idea how to do this.

Comment: There are some APIs built on the IMDB data ([details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1966503/2327328)), but none seem to include the actor details you require.

Comment: Or DIY with python and the text files: https://github.com/nandhp/python-imdb

Comment: Some actors/actresses don't want their birthdate (and hence their age) known as it can bias people against hiring them.  If they can pass for 30-50, knowing they're actually 45 might keep them from getting the younger roles.  (this is even more likely for actresses)

Comment: Naturally, when no DOB is known ....
So, me personally, i try to focus on the data that is there.

Comment: @GwenKillerby Not for every actor, but for the ones IMDB has a birthday, I might be able to help. I am just building that database others refered to.

Answer (score 5):

Have you taken a look at http://www.imdb.com/interfaces which includes a link to FTP mirrors where you can get data files that can presumably be joined in a RDBMS or other type of database system. Files you probably want to investigate are `actors.list.gz`, `movies.list.gz`, and `release-dates.list.gz`

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, already got those, but how would I use them? I got no experience with MySQL or any RDBMS

Comment: If you know a programming language but not SQL, then you can use steps from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/622308/2327328)

Comment: BTW, the files are just text files. For example, the release date file has lines like this: `Arizona Dream (1992) USA:9 September 1994
`. With some preprocessing you can import them to Excel or Access. One issue may be the large file sizes.

Comment: I know they are just text files, and this is the problem. Fields aren't properly separated by commas or tabs or whatever.

Comment: I know they are textfiles, this is the problem, fields arent' properly separated by commas or tabs or whatever. Also, the actress file doesn't have Date of Birth info.

Comment: Looks like releases are separated by colons?

Comment: I didnt' see colons in the Actress.list file  in the GZ archive .....???
I got that from here:
ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/tv+movies/imdb/actresses.list.gz

Answer (score -1):

as I know imdb has not official api but some unofficial data is available for example: [omsbapi](http://www.omdbapi.com/) also there is a useful api for [yts](http://www.omdbapi.com/)

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/254520) for why)